# Bar plot for multiple data in same dates Python

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

I have four different data sets with the same x-axis that I'd like to plot as bar plots. The x axis is biweekly dates. I'm having trouble plotting this without the bars overlapping and without having to shift the x date, which would be inaccurate.

I have the data saved in a `pandas dataframe`, hoping that it'd be easier?

```
dates:           data        type 1         type 2        type 3              
10/22/2015         0           1              2             3
11/5/2015          5           6              5             7
11/19/2015         10          5              11            12
12/3/2015          15          10             14            2
12/17/2015         20          15             21            18
12/31/2015         25          20             24            14
1/14/2016         -30         -24            -31           -16 
1/28/2016         -35         -20            -33           -36
2/11/2016         -40         -28            -39           -8
2/25/2016         -45         -40            -45           -39
```

Comment: Can you please the add you code

Comment: if you just want to plot 4 axes in one figure use `fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,4):  for i,axi in enumerate(ax.flat): axi.bar(your Data)`

Comment: See that example : https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html

Comment: I keep getting this error 'max must be larger than min in range parameter.' when I use the code from  matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/.